# Why are my 3 footer images go really big each time I change or reload a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem where 3 of my images in the footer which  are small appear really big which isn't their normal size each time I reload a page or change to a different page of my website. If you hover  over them they return to their normal size but it happens each time you load a page. I have javascript which make the 3 images enlarge on mouse over and go back to normal size on mouse out.

Here  is the html

```
<div id="footer">

Contact | Privacy Policy | Call 1300 IT 4 U (483 678)
<br />
 <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> Pty Ltd 2000-2014 is proudly powered by<a 

href="http://wordpress.org/">WordPress</a> and designed by <a 

href="http://www.wpart.org/">WPart.</a> All Rights Reserved. Stathis Arcade 262 Maquarie Street  Suite 2-3 | Liverpool NSW 2170`
<br />
 <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/ostech-pty-ltd."><img onmouseover="enlarge(this)"   onmouseout="normal(this)" src="/wp-content/themes/bluefantasy/images/LinkedIn_icon.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/OSTechCorp"><img onmouseover="enlarge(this)" onmouseout="normal(this)" src="/wp-content/themes/bluefantasy/images/facebook_icon.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/ostech"><img onmouseover="enlarge(this)" onmouseout="normal(this)" src="/wp-content/themes/bluefantasy/images/Twitter_icon.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
 <br />
</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<head>
<script>
function enlarge(x)
    {
        x.style.height="64px";
        x.style.width="64px";
    }

function normal(x)
    {
        x.style.height="32px";
        x.style.width="32px";   
    }
</script>
</head>
```

Here is the footer css in case it is the css but I doubt it:

```
#footer {

    width: 960px;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    padding-top: 10px;

    clear:both;

    height: auto;

    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;

    font-size: 12px;

    font-weight: normal;

    color: #002899 !important;


    text-align: center;


    overflow: hidden;

}
```

Comment: Would you mind including a link to the page in question?

Answer (score 1):

you may want to set the default values for the img size, that way they load with the expected size.

so you would want to add something like this to your css

```
#footer img { 
   width: 32px; 
   height: 32px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified a size in your HTML code, the images are displayed with the original size. Once you mouse over, the size of the image is set to 64 by 64 and when you move out the size is changed to 32.

To fix it, you need to specify width and height of your images in the html code

*width="32px" height="32px"*

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/ostech-pty-ltd."><img onmouseover="enlarge(this)"   onmouseout="normal(this)" src="/wp-content/themes/bluefantasy/images/LinkedIn_icon.png" alt="LinkedIn" width="32px" height="32px"></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/OSTechCorp"><img onmouseover="enlarge(this)" onmouseout="normal(this)" src="/wp-content/themes/bluefantasy/images/facebook_icon.png" alt="Facebook" width="32px" height="32px"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/ostech"><img onmouseover="enlarge(this)" onmouseout="normal(this)" src="/wp-content/themes/bluefantasy/images/Twitter_icon.png" alt="Twitter" width="32px" height="32px"></a>
```

Probably cleaner is to specify width and height in your css.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I forgot about the width and height in the html. Is there a way to change it into a fisheye bubble up selector?

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
     #footer { 
        width: 32px; 
        height: 32px; 
      }
```